# Is there a natural way to view $\bigwedge^k_{\mathbb{C}}\mathbb{C}^d$ as a subspace of $\bigwedge^k_{\mathbb{R}}\mathbb{C}^d$

Tags: differential-geometry, tensor-products, complex-geometry, exterior-algebra, grassmannian

> Does there exists an $\mathbb R$-linear embedding $\bigwedge^k_{\mathbb{C}}\mathbb{C}^d \to \bigwedge^k_{\mathbb{R}}\mathbb{C}^d$ which maps decomposable tensors to decomposable tensors?

(The subscripts specify over which field we are taking the tensor/exterior powers. )

**I specifically want an embedding which respects the "Grassmannian" structures of the exterior powers.** *Some* embedding always exists, due to [dimensional reasons](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3099711/is-2-binomdk-le-binom2dk-true):

$\dim_{\mathbb R}(\bigwedge^k_{\mathbb{C}}\mathbb{C}^d)=2\binom{d}{k} \le 
 \binom{2d}{k} =\dim_{\mathbb R}(\bigwedge^k_{\mathbb{R}}\mathbb{C}^d).$

---

The naive candidate would be to take $v_1 \wedge \dots \wedge v_k$ to "itself". However, this does not really define a well-defined map $\bigwedge^k_{\mathbb{C}}\mathbb{C}^d \to \bigwedge^k_{\mathbb{R}}\mathbb{C}^d$. For $k=2$, $iv_1 \wedge v_2=v_1 \wedge iv_2$ are equal as elements of $\bigwedge^k_{\mathbb{C}}\mathbb{C}^d$, but not are not always equal as elements of $\bigwedge^k_{\mathbb{R}}\mathbb{C}^d$:

Set $v_1=\begin{equation}
 \left(\matrix{
   1 \cr
   i\cr
}\right)
\end{equation},$
$
 v_2=\begin{equation}
 \left(\matrix{
   -i \cr
   0\cr
}\right)
\end{equation}$. Then $\text{span}_{\mathbb R}(v_1,iv_2)=\text{span}_{\mathbb R}(\left(\matrix{
   1 \cr
   i\cr
}\right),\left(\matrix{
  1 \cr
   0\cr
}\right)) \neq \text{span}_{\mathbb R}(\left(\matrix{
   i \cr
   -1\cr
}\right),\left(\matrix{
  -i \cr
   0\cr
}\right))  = \text{span}_{\mathbb R}(iv_1,v_2)$, so
$v_1 \wedge iv_2 , iv_1 \wedge v_2$ are not equal as elements of $\bigwedge^k_{\mathbb{R}}\mathbb{C}^d$.

---

*Comment:* I don't really know how to construct $\mathbb{R}$-linear maps
from $\bigwedge^k_{\mathbb{C}}\mathbb{C}^d$, since the usual universal property of exterior power, only give a way to construct $\mathbb{C}$-linear maps.

Comment: Note that $\bigwedge_{\Bbb{C}}^k\Bbb{C}^d$ is naturally a quotient of $\bigwedge_{\Bbb{R}}^k\Bbb{C}^d$. Are you looking for a section of the quotient map?

Comment: Well, I am looking for an $\mathbb R$-linear embedding which maps decomposable tensors to decomposable tensors, and takes $\bigwedge^k {\mathbb R}^d$ inside  $\bigwedge^k_{\mathbb{C}}\mathbb{C}^d $ to its counterpart in $\bigwedge^k_{\mathbb{R}}\mathbb{C}^d$.  (You can see here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3098324/if-omega-in-bigwedgek-mathbbrd-is-decomposable-over-mathbb-c-is-it... for further motivation and explanation of how I view $\bigwedge^k {\mathbb R}^d$ as a subspace of both $\bigwedge^k_{\mathbb{C}}\mathbb{C}^d $ and $\bigwedge^k_{\mathbb{R}}\mathbb{C}^d$).

Comment: By the way, can you elaborate on how $\bigwedge_{\Bbb{C}}^k\Bbb{C}^d$ is realized as a quotient of $\bigwedge_{\Bbb{R}}^k\Bbb{C}^d $? I don't see it...